# Masonite: Migrations for production data

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

Actually, I can't import Masonite's models properly inside my migration file. I want to create pre-registered data as database seeds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `__init__.py` file in your migrations directory and put this in it:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```